For $A$ adjacency matrix, $\text{adj}(tI-A)$ has no zero columns when $t=\lambda$ (eigenvalue). True or false?
Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of a graph, and let $\lambda$ be one of its eigenvalues with multiplicity $m$. In particular I know that I can write the characteristic polynomial as $\phi(X,t)=(t-\lambda)^mq(t)$ for some polynomial $q(t)$ that does not vanish at $\lambda$.
Suppose we look at $(tI-A)^{-1}$, which we can rewrite as follows:
$$(tI-A)^{-1}_{u,v}=\frac{\phi_{u,v}(X,t)}{\phi(X,t)},$$
where $\phi_{u,v}(X,t)$ is the determinant of $tI-A$ with the $u^{th}$ row and $v^{th}$ column deleted (i.e. the entries of $\text{adj}(tI-A)$). I am able to show that $\frac{\phi_{u,v}(X,t)}{\phi(X,t)}$ has only simple poles. Since $\phi(X,t)=(t-\lambda)^mq(t)$, this means that $\phi_{u,v}(X,t)=(t-\lambda)^{m-1}B_{u,v}(t)$, where $B(t)$ is another matrix. However, it may happen that $B_{u,v}(\lambda)=0$ for some $u,v$, although I have the intuition that not a full row/column of $B(\lambda)$ can be zero. I don't know how to show this, however. Could someone help me?

I assume adj refers to the adjugate. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity greater than $1$, then $\text{adj}(\lambda I - A) = 0$, so it certainly has a zero-column. In general, $\text{adj}(M) = 0$ if and only if the rank of $M$ is less than $n - 1$ (where $n$ is the size of $M$).

Also, in general, $\text{adj}(M)$ will have a zero column if and only if $M$ has rank $n-1$ and one column of $M$ is outside the span of all other columns. For a symmetric matrix $A$, if $\text{adj}(A - \lambda I)$ is non-zero but has a zero column, then $\lambda$ has multiplicity $1$ and the eigenvector associated with $\lambda$ has a zero-entry.

@BenGrossmann Thank you for your comment. How do you know that $\text{adj}(\lambda I-A)=0$? We have that $\text{adj}(\lambda I-A)=(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\text{det}(\lambda I-A)$, and I know that the determinant bit is $0$, but what if the inverse had poles in some entries, cancelling out the zeroes?

To justify my first comment, when $M$ has rank $n-2$, the determinantal rank being smaller than $n-2$ means that all entries of $\text{adj}(M)$ are zero. If $\lambda$ has multiplicity $m \geq 2$, then $\lambda I - A$ has rank $n - m$, so $\text{adj}(\lambda I - A) = 0$

@BenGrossmann what if I take the $m^{th}$ derivative of $\text{adj}(tI-A)$ and evaluate it at $t=\lambda$? Can I be sure that all the columns will be nonzero? If so, why?
